# Do I need to specify type="submit" on submit buttons?

Tags: html, forms, browser, specifications

Previously, when I've had a form with a single submit button on it, I've usually not put the `type="submit"` attribute in there. I've never observed this causing problems, and had believed that "submit" was the default type for a button and that I could rely on this behaviour.

However, w3schools and MDN disagree on whether I am right.

[w3schools claims:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp)

> **Tip**: Always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element. Different browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element.

whereas [MDN claims:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> - `submit`: ... This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Who is right and who is wrong - both according to spec, and in real browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MDN has some spec links near the bottom of its article which confirm that what it says is correct: the default `type` of a `button` element is `submit`.

[W3C HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5):

> `type` = `submit|button|reset` [CI]
> This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> - `submit:` Creates a submit button. This is the default value.
> - `reset:` Creates a reset button.
> - `button:` Creates a push button.

[W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element):

> The `type` attribute controls the behavior of the button when it is activated. It is an enumerated attribute. The following table lists the keywords and states for the attribute — the keywords in the left column map to the states in the cell in the second column on the same row as the keyword.
>
> ```
> Keyword | State         | Brief description
> --------+---------------+------------------
> submit  | Submit Button | Submits the form.
> reset   | Reset Button  | Resets the form.
> button  | Button        | Does nothing.
> ```
>
> The *missing value default* is the Submit Button state.

What W3Schools is saying is that you should always specify the attribute to ensure as consistent behavior across browsers as possible. That doesn't imply that the attribute cannot legally be omitted.

Comment: *What W3Schools is saying is that you should always specify the attribute to ensure as consistent behavior across browsers as possible. It doesn't imply that the attribute cannot be omitted.* - Hmm. I wouldn't be that charitable. They claim *Different browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element* - which, according to the spec quotes you've posted, is simply outright false. The only way what they're saying could be defensible is if there exist actual browsers that don't conform to the spec in this regard.

Comment: @Mark Amery: I clarified my last statement a bit.

Comment: [off-topic] There was a movement of a few important people saying w3schools should be banned from the internet and w3c specs should be consulted instead.

Comment: Yeah because clearly I can't even explain a harmless statement made by W3Schools without implying that I endorse them.